# Does it automatically fail-over and How much time Automatic SQL Azure Fail-over takes

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are planning to setup the SQL Azure Fail-over groups with automatic fail-over and grace period 1 hour which is minimum.
We would like to know if the Primary Database is down then would it fail-over immediately? or do we need to wait for 1 hour, which is a long time in case of Disaster. Or is it that we have to always fail-over manually?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With automatic failover groups the RTO is 1 hour as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity#sql-database-features-that-you-can-use-to-provide-business-continuity), where RTO is known as recovery time objective or the time required for application to fully recover.

While failover itself takes only a few seconds, the service will take at least 1 hour to activate it (RTO). This is necessary to ensure that the failover is justified by the scale of the outage. Also, the failover may result in small data loss (RPO) due to the nature of asynchronous replication. With automatic failover the RPO is 5 seconds. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-business-continuity#recover-a-database-to-another-region) for more information.

Comment: Thank you @Alberto. i had gone through those document, so when the actual disaster happens it means our secondary SQL Server would be active within an hour? Do we need to do the fail-over manually so that the secondary becomes primary immediately. Also, is there any way to test this without manual-failover?

Comment: "While failover itself takes only a few seconds, the service will take at least 1 hour to activate it" - this really does read like "failover takes a few seconds to run, but will only run **after** 1 hour" - and the paragraph doesn't explain *exactly* what happens in that preceding hour. Is my application supposed to just sit there with broken connections for an hour?